# Binding keys in Elite Dangerous

Tags: pc, elite-dangerous

[image: Elite Dangerous key binding screen]

I notice there are two columns where you can click to bind keys. In the image you can see the 'thrust down' has two bindings. I don't see any labels to explain when the two different bindings are used. Why are there two slots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have two keys bound to the same effect.

In your example, both [Down Arrow] and [Mouse 1] will activate Thrust Down.